# Как корректно применить два одинаковых кода на одной странице?

Tags: javascript

Первый код

```
    <ul id="slides2">
  <li class="slide2"> современную </li>
  <li class="slide2 showing"> умную </li>
  <li class="slide2"> гибкую </li>
</ul>
<script type="text/javascript">
var slides = document.querySelectorAll('#slides2 .slide2');
var currentSlide = 0;
var slideInterval = setInterval(nextSlide,3000);

function nextSlide(){
    slides[currentSlide].className = 'slide22';
    currentSlide = (currentSlide+1)%slides.length;
    slides[currentSlide].className = 'slide2 showing';
}
</script>
<style>
#slides2{
    position: relative;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    list-style-type: none;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.slide2{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: top 1s;
    top: 100%;

    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s;
    -o-transition: opacity 1s;
    transition: opacity 1s;
}
.showing{
    top: 0;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: top 1s, opacity 0s;
    z-index: 2;
}
.slide2 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Montserrat";
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 62px;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /*color: #ffffff;*/
}
</style>
```

Второй код. Меняю id повторяющихся элементов, но что-то делаю неправильно

```
    <ul id="slides">
  <li class="slide"> Управляйте производством</li>
  <li class="slide showing"> Контролируйте процессы</li>
  <li class="slide"> Повышайте эффективность</li>
</ul>
<script type="text/javascript">
var slides = document.querySelectorAll('#slides .slide');
var currentSlide = 0;
var slideInterval = setInterval(nextSlide,3000);

function nextSlide(){
    slides[currentSlide].className = 'slide';
    currentSlide = (currentSlide+1)%slides.length;
    slides[currentSlide].className = 'slide showing';
}
</script>
<style>
#slides{
    position: relative;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    list-style-type: none;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.slide{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: top 1s;
    top: 100%;

    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s;
    -o-transition: opacity 1s;
    transition: opacity 1s;
}
.showing{
    top: 0;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: top 1s, opacity 0s;
    z-index: 2;
}
.slide {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Montserrat";
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 62px;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /*color: #ffffff;*/
}
</style>
```

Comment: Дополните вопрос: Что из представленного, является *"2 одинаковых кода"*? Применить к чему? Что у вас должно происходить? т.е. какого результата вы хотите достичь и что не получилось?

Comment: Это один код, нужен такой же, но для другого текста. Коды используются на одной странице и соответственно конфликтуют друг с другом. Меняю id повторяющихся элементов, но видно неправильно

Comment: Обновите ваш код в вопросе и покажите, что вы пытались сделать

Comment: Как эти 2 кода связаны между собой? Это одна и та же страница?

Comment: да, будут использоваться на одной странице, но для разных текстов

Answer (score 0):

Во первых: избавляйтесь от [устаревшего ключевого слова var](https://learn.javascript.ru/var)

Для возможности использовать один скрипт на несколько элементов, в вашем случае, можно сделать функцию(используется магия замыканий), которая будет служить контейнером для счетчика.

```js
const first = document.querySelectorAll('#slides .slide');
const second = document.querySelectorAll('#slides2 .slide2');

function nexSlide(slides, time) {
  let currentSlide = 0;

  function nextSlideTick() {
    slides[currentSlide].className = 'slide';
    currentSlide = (currentSlide + 1) % slides.length;
    slides[currentSlide].className = 'slide showing';
  }
  return setInterval(nextSlideTick, time); // Возвращаем ID интервала
}

const firstTimer = nexSlide(first, 2000); // Через clearInterval(firstTimer) можно остановить листание 
const secondTimer = nexSlide(second, 1500);
```

```css
#slides2 {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  list-style-type: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slide2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: top 1s;
  top: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s;
  -o-transition: opacity 1s;
  transition: opacity 1s;
}

.showing {
  top: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: top 1s, opacity 0s;
  z-index: 2;
}

.slide2 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Montserrat";
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 62px;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /*color: #ffffff;*/
}

#slides {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  list-style-type: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slide {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: top 1s;
  top: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s;
  -o-transition: opacity 1s;
  transition: opacity 1s;
}

.showing {
  top: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: top 1s, opacity 0s;
  z-index: 2;
}

.slide {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Montserrat";
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 62px;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /*color: #ffffff;*/
}
```

```html
<ul id="slides2">
  <li class="slide2"> современную </li>
  <li class="slide2 showing"> умную </li>
  <li class="slide2"> гибкую </li>
</ul>
<hr />
<ul id="slides">
  <li class="slide"> Управляйте производством</li>
  <li class="slide showing"> Контролируйте процессы</li>
  <li class="slide"> Повышайте эффективность</li>
</ul>
```